# Java - editable and searchable list of strings

Tags: java, string, list

I want to make a searchable and editable list of strings. So I want to search in it and I want to add strings to it when the program is running.

Something like this:

```
String[] list  // how should this line look like?
list.add("qq");
list.add("ww"); 
if(list.contains("qq")) {
    //do something
}
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Can you please provide any code examples to clarify what you try to achieve? You can add objects to the instance of ArrayList class and then search them in there, but it's hard to tell what you need.

Comment: Java already gives you `List` (with many implementations like `ArrayList`) which already does what you say. Do you have any specific problem with using it?

Comment: Something like this: `String[] list; list.add("qq") list.add("ww"); if(list.contains("qq")) {do something};`

Comment: Please visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html Simply use `List<String> list  = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: [```java.util.ArrayList```](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) will do what you want.